# Syntax highlight colors in Code Composer Studio

Tags: ide, texas-instruments

I've trying to change color of the syntax highlight in Code Composer Studio. 
It is not like native Eclipse under `Preference >> <programming language> >> Editor`".

Where do I find the option to setup the syntax colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where these are! You have to click "Show Advanced Settings" at the bottom of the Preferences popup. Then you will get a C++ section with syntax colors.